# Change jQuery autocomplete

Tags: javascript, jquery, drop-down-menu, jquery-autocomplete

jQuery has an autocomplete code that works like the search box on google.  However it doesn't allow for the drop down items to be clickable links.  I'm not that great with jQuery.  Is there any way to alter the jQuery autocomplete code to make the items links?

Also if possible i would like to alter that code again so that when the user uses the arrow keys to scroll down the dropdown, the hovered item doesnt appear in the search box

Heres the link to the jQuery code: http://jqueryui.com/demos/autocomplete/

Answer (score 3):

It's right there in the docs:
http://jqueryui.com/demos/autocomplete/#event-select
You must change the select event appropriately:

```
$( ".selector" ).autocomplete({
   select: function(event, ui) { window.location = "www.google.com"
   }
});
```

Comment: thanks.  one more question.  is there any way to not show the hovered menu item in the textbox?

Answer (score 0):

There is a way for you to control the actual html that is displayed.

It is in fact shown on the page you linked to

http://jqueryui.com/demos/autocomplete/#custom-data

There is no reason why you should not be able to make the drop down links.